# After define the header breaks dont work anymore

Tags: php, html, contact-form

after I define a PHP header with UTF-8 my breaks on $msg don't work anymore.
Where is the problem? Is there another way to make breaks?

Thanks!

Code:

```
<?php  

$username = $_POST['name'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$useremail = $_POST['mail'];
  $fon = $_POST['phone'];
$usermsg = $_POST['nachricht'];
$myemail = "Mail@XY";

$msg = "Antwort an: $useremail\n". "Name: $username $lastname \n". "Telefonnummer: $fon \n". "Nachricht: $usermsg";

$subject = "Neue Nachricht vom Kontaktformular";

$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'. "\r\n"
          .'From: ' . $myemail . "\r\n";

if(empty($username)||empty($useremail)||empty($usermsg)){
  header("location:index.html?error");
}

else{
  $to = "Mail@XY";
  mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `utf-8` which has caused this, it's the `text/html`.

You're telling the receiving mail client to parse and display the email as a HTML document. As you hopefully know, in HTML a line break is specified using the [`<br>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br). HTML rendering engines do not take any notice of `\n` or `\r\n` - these are only useful in plain-text documents.

This:

```
$msg = "Antwort an: $useremail<br>". "Name: $username $lastname <br>". "Telefonnummer: $fon <br>". "Nachricht: $usermsg";
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$msg = "Antwort an: $useremail\n". "Name: $username $lastname \n". "Telefonnummer: $fon \n". "Nachricht: $usermsg";
```

If you aim HTML-mail format, `\n`s in the `$msg` must be replaced with the HTML tag `<br>`.

```
$msg = "Antwort an: $useremail<br>". "Name: $username $lastname<br>". "Telefonnummer: $fon<br>". "Nachricht: $usermsg";
```

If you aim text-mail format then try [PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) or `\r\n` instead of `\n` in your `$msg`.

Comment: PHP_EOL won't respect the target format of the mail, it'll only respect the current PHP environment (e.g. web or command line).